# How is the SharePoint FX's integration with Angular?

Tags: sharepoint

How is the SharePoint FX's integration with Angular? I know it has good support for React, but want to know the pros and cons of SharePoint Framework with Angular 6+

Answer (score 0):

Lets update some of the files for Angular to work with SharePoint Framework.

**package.json**

```
"@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/elements": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
"@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.1.1",
"core-js": "^2.5.7",
"rxjs": "^6.2.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.26"
```

**tsconfig.json**

This is the TypeScript configuration file for the IDE. Open tsconfig.json file, add below line under "**compilerOptions**".

```
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
```

**gulpfile.js**

This file defines all the tasks for the project like compiling TypeScript files to JavaScript, bundle and minify JS/CSS files etc. We need to modify the build process. Open "gulpfile.js" file and add below code just above the "build.initialize" line.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

build.configureWebpack.mergeConfig({
   additionalConfiguration: (generatedConfiguration) => {

      generatedConfiguration.plugins.push(new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)fesm5/, path.join(__dirname, './client')));

      return generatedConfiguration;
   }
});
```

Here are two solution with source code about use Angular 6 in SharePoint framework for your reference.

[Angular Demo Webpart](https://github.com/joergkrause/angular-spfx-fabric-boilerplate)

[Angular Elements in SharePoint Framework](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/angularelements-helloworld)